# Как проверить подписался ли пользователь на группу или канал в Telegram,

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток.

Захотел сделать сайтец для взаимной подписки на группы в телеге. И встал такой вопрос.
Есть ли способ проверить подписался ли пользователь на определенный канал или группу в телеграм?

На просторах гугла и в api самого телеграм что то не нашел внятной информации. Если есть решение моей задачи напишите пожалуйста куда копать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть 2 способа. Для обоих требуются админ права у Бота

1. Самый простой - использовать метод [getChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember)

При действиях пользователя с помощью данного метода проверять подписку

2. Посложнее - следить за [ChatMemberUpdate](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmemberupdated)

При подписке давать возможность пользоваться ботом. При отписке отключать

Comment: При первом способе бота нужно добавить в группу и сделать его администратором? Я правильно понял.

Comment: Да, все так. Без добавления и админ прав работать ничего не будет

Comment: спасибо, пойду писать бота.